# how to search data using one and more field name wise in mySql

Tags: mysql

```
deviceId               deviceName           deviceNumber      deviceWorkingStatus   os             resolution                displayDensity   serialNo           remarks         status


'1'                   'HTC Magic'            'TJ/AND-01'              '0'       'Android - 1.5'    '320 x 480'                'Medium'     'HT96WKF00400'        'Using by Amit'   '1'
'6'                 'HTC Desire C'            'TJ/AND-06'             '1'       'Android 4.0'     'HVGA, 480 x 320 Pixels'     NULL        'SH29XW504394'           NULL            '1'
```

this is my Table i want to search by following name or any of one or combination these fields

`deviceId`,`searchTerm`,`deviceName`,`deviceNumber`,`os`,`Android`,`deviceWorkingStatus`,`status`

where `searchTerm` is combination of all fields, please suggest me how to write query for search of all parameter of one or combination of two three..

`deviceId`, `deviceName` `deviceNumber`, `deviceWorkingStatus`, `os`, `resolution`, `displayDensity`, `serialNo`, `remarks`, `status`

Comment: Where are you doing research?

Comment: means i have to Search it

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Can you re-phrase it again?

Comment: look i have concat and serch data from table like select  * from  table where deviceName='deviceName '  if input deviceName if we input deviceName and deviceNumber then it should serch by device name and also deviceNumber wise like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are the search parameters and you want search result based on any combination of those you need a query covering all those fields.

- deviceId
- searchTerm
- deviceName
- deviceNumber
- os
- Android
- deviceWorkingStatus
- status

  ---

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
*
FROM your_table
WHERE deviceId LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(deviceIdSearchString,''),'%')
AND searchTerm LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(searchTermSearchString,''),'%')
AND deviceName LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(deviceNameSearchString,''),'%')
AND deviceNumber LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(deviceNumberSearchString,''),'%')
AND os LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(osSearchString,''),'%')
AND Android LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(AndroidSearchString,''),'%')
AND deviceWorkingStatus LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(deviceWorkingStatus,''),'%')
AND status LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(statusSearchString,''),'%');
```

**Note:**

If you want to get results event if the search string is empty then this would work.

Comment: OK thanx let me check

Comment: u there please i need one help

Answer (score 1):

How About this way:

```
set @param = '';
SELECT 
*
FROM tbl_device
WHERE deviceId LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or deviceName LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or deviceNumber LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or os LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or resolution LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or deviceWorkingStatus LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or  serialNo LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or displayDensity LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or remarks LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%')
or status LIKE CONCAT('%',COALESCE(@param ,''),'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have asked, I only have a rough idea of what is your objective. So, if you want to query by more than two columns in a `WHERE` clause, you can add an `AND` in between

Example:

`SELECT * from Table WHERE deviceName = 'deviceName' AND deviceNumber = 'deviceNumber'`

Comment: But some time when we pass no devicenumber then this query wont work because it will be null @ALVIN

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment if that's the case, you can use `OR`